# ANDROID STUDIO GIT with TFS

Tags: android, git, tfs, version-control, azure-devops

I am using GIT with TFS for the version control in my android studio

What is use of TFS here with GIT. Becuase GIT has default control in studio. What does TFS does here
[image]

Comment: I am using GIT along with TFS. Sorry for the wrong mention of question.

Comment: Have you looked up a data sheet with the capabilities of TFS? It's far more than version control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Git** option is the way for your to clone a remote git repo locally. Such as the remote repo can be your own setup, hosted on github, bitbucket, VSTS or TFS etc.

**Team Service Git** option is allow you to connect git repo on VSTS and TFS in a seamless and intuitive way. It shows here because you installed **visual studio team services plugin** in android studio, the plugin has below features:

> Features
>
> - Supports authenticating with Team Services and TFS 2015+ to work with source code in Git and TFVC repositories.
> - Checkout code from Git and TFVC repositories on Visual Studio Team Services and TFS 2015+.
> - Git specific features:
>
>   - Import IntelliJ projects into Git repositories on Team Services and TFS 2015+.
>   - Create pull requests and view your active pull requests.
>   - Create a new branch and associate it with the work item you are working on.
>   - Quickly browse to file history or commit details on the web from the IDE.
> - TFVC specific features:
>
>   - Execute all basic version control actions such as add, delete, rename, move, etc.
>   - View local changes and history for your files.
>   - Lock and unlock files and directories.
>   - Add labels to files and directories.
>   - Create, view, and edit a workspace.
>   - Supports using a TFS proxy.
>   - Local workspace support only.
> - View work items based on queries and select one or more work items to associate with your commits or checkins.
> - Check the build status of your repository and queue a new build if desired.
> - Supports proxy settings configured in the IDE's System Settings section.
> - Edit cached project information through configuration management.